# Looping out JSON Array using ArrayList

Tags: android, json, for-loop, arraylist, retrofit2

I am trying to learn retrofit and I have made successful attempts at posting data and now I am trying to retrieve JSON array which looks as follows:

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "message": "All Questions Have Been Selected",
  "question": {
      "all_question_ids": ["1","2","3"]
  }
}
```

I am using the following getter

```
public ArrayList getAll_question_ids(){
     return all_question_ids;
  }
```

I am retrieving using Retrofit as follows

```
if (resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                Log.d("Question_IDs", "getAllQuestionID() = " + response.body().getQuestion().getAll_question_ids() );

                editor.putString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS,((resp.getQuestion().getAll_question_ids().toString())));
                editor.apply();

            }
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

It is here that I am stuck, as I am retrieving the array ok but I am unsure how to loop out the Array which is now stored in **Shared Preferences**.

When I place a toast to show me how the IDs are coming across, my toast confirms the data as [1,2,3]

The goal is to add a dynamic button and the individual ID, i.e button 1, button 2 etc every-time the loop is iterated.

I have tried the following:

```
String questionNumber = pref.getString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS, "");

 for (int i =0; i < questionNumber.length(); i++) {


            try {

        /*Dynamically create new Button which includes the question name
          */

                AppCompatButton btn_question = new AppCompatButton(getActivity());

        /*LayoutParams (int width, int height,float weight)
        As LayoutParams is defaulted in px, I have called a method called dpToPX to make sure
        the dynamically added EditText is the same size on all devices.
         */
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx(280), dpToPx(45), 1);
                btn_question.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3B5998"));
                btn_question.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
               // btn_question.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                btn_question.setText("Question "+ pref.getString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS,""));
                btn_question.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                //generate unique ID for each new EditText dynamically created
                View.generateViewId();

                //Log.d("TEST VALUE", "Question1 generated ID = " + btn_question.generateViewId());


                params.setMargins(0, dpToPx(10), 0, dpToPx(10));
                btn_question.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                btn_question.setLayoutParams(params);
                allEds.add(btn_question);
                mLayout.addView(btn_question);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to create new edit text");
            }
        }
```

However the above is adding the value as it appears in the array e.g [1,2,3] which is obviously not what I want.

I have added a photo in case my explanation isn't clear. I want a button with 1 number added to it each time the loop iterates but I am unable to figure this out.

I have looked through lots of resource but cannot find an answer that is relevant to my problem, although, if there is, I am not familiar enough to recognise a similar issue.

If someone can offer some assistance, I would appreciate it!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `editor.putString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS,((SOMETHING.toString())));`, what is actually stored depends on the implementation of the `toString` method in the type of `SOMETHING` (in this case `String[]`). So avoid doing that. Instead, since you're already using Gson or Jackson (or others), store the `question_ids`as JSON:

```
final String jsonIds = gson.toJson (resp.getQuestion().getAll_question_ids());
editor.putString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS, jsonIds);
```

Your actual stored value no longer depends on the implementation of something that you don't control (String[].toString). It is a valid JSON array and regardless of what tool/library you use to read it back, it's valid.

Now, to read back the stored data:

```
final String storedJson = pref.getString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS, null);
if (null == storedJson) {
  // TODO: No question ids found
}

final String[] ids = gson.fromJson (storedJson, String[].class);
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  // make your buttons
}
```

Comment: You can get `resp` as a raw string. Then you're not serializing what was just deserialized

Comment: Only a part of the response is being stored, not the entire thing.

Comment: Right, and you can extract out that part via the raw data

Comment: @copolii after all this time, I came back to look at this answer and realised that this is the best solution all along! I have now accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of saving and then reading out a `List` of items (in this case, `String` instances).

You've chosen to save the list by calling `editor.putString()` with a value of `getAll_question_ids().toString()`. That `toString()` call is going to return a *string representation* of your list, or, in other words, a `String` instance with the value `[1, 2, 3]`. At this point, you no longer have a `List` proper, but a `String` that looks like a list.

This is all technically fine, but it means you have to take this into account when you're trying to read out that list.

You've written this to read the list back out:

```
String questionNumber = pref.getString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS, "");
```

Once this line executes, `questionNumber` will be a `String` instance with the value `[1, 2, 3]`. Again, this is fine, but now we come to the key point: we have to convert this `String` back into a `List`.

If you **know for sure** that the values in this list won't have commas in them, you can do it easily:

- Trim the braces off the string using `substring()`
- Create a `String[]` using `split()`
- Convert your array to a list using `Arrays.asList()` (you could even skip this step since iterating over an array is just as easy as iterating over a list)

Put that together and you get:

```
String questionNumber = pref.getString(Constants.All_QUESTION_IDS, "");
questionNumber = questionNumber.substring(1, questionNumber.length() - 1);
String[] array = questionNumber.split(", ");
List list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

At this point, you can iterate over your array or list:

```
for (String value : list) {
    ...
    btn_question.setText("Question " + value);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Or you could just put and get a `JSONArray`... substring off the brackets is just a workaround

Comment: @cricket_007 OP doesn't have a `JSONArray` instance to work with, and either way they're trying to use `SharedPreferences` which can only store `String` or `Set<String>`, so I'm answering in the spirit of their question.

Comment: all_question_ids is definitely a JSONArray. Take away Retrofit parsing it to an Arraylist, and it'll be there